How to rank a totaledd column with Dax as a calculated Column
I have a dataset that has Grocery store name, department name, Employee name... I am trying to Count the number of employees by department to get a total number of employees by department and then rank the department from largest (1) to smallest across each grocery store. Any ideas on how to do this?
To functions here -- total up the number of employees and then rank them.. I attached an image of my dataset and the column I am trying to create (yellow column).
Thank you so much for any help / suggestions. I really appreciate.
Dataset & Result
I Tried the below formula and it works. It ranks the departments largest to smallest, but it does not break it up by the store... so meat will be 1, produce/toys/electronics will be 2, frozen/stocker will be 3, deli/outdoor will be 4.. in relation to all grocery stores.. I need Toys to be 1 etc.
=RANKX (
ALL ( table1[store]),
    CALCULATE(COUNTA([EmployeeName]), ALLExcept(table1,table1[store])))

`

you can try this
Column =
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Store],
        'Table'[Product],
        "count", COUNT ( 'Table'[Employee Name] )
    )
VAR _tbl2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _tbl,
        "rank", RANKX ( FILTER ( _tbl, [Store] = EARLIER ( [Store] ) ), [count],, DESC )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            _tbl2,
            'Table'[Store] = EARLIER ( [Store] )
                && 'Table'[Product] = EARLIER ( [Product] )
        ),
        [rank]
    )


